# Is there a method to smooth polygons and force all angles to be 90 degrees?

Tags: python, polygon

Is there a way to smooth jagged polygons and get nice 90 degree angles like in the image below? Are any algorithms or methods available?

I've tried GeoPandas' `.simplify()` function, which uses the  Douglas-Peucker algorithm, but the results aren't as smooth and the quality of results varies depending on the shape of the polygon.

Are there any existing algorithms or approaches to achieve this?

[image]

[Image Source here.](https://github.com/microsoft/AustraliaBuildingFootprints?fbclid=IwAR0FS7JEHLHxiRuxwCcEXWlSrlsnDxvdfAIj7o9K0yYA5Ol2llG21Vj16FA)

Comment: Check `Orthogonalize` tool in QGIS and this may works for you: https://github.com/Mashin6/orthogonalize-polygon

Comment: Ramer-Douglas-Peucker is a *simplification* algorithm, not a *smoothing* tool. You may need to code something to meet your criteria.